# facebook 'like box' plugin does not compensate for the header / faces being switched off

Tags: facebook, plugins

When using the facebook 'like box' plugin without a header and faces there is a gap left at the bottom. This even happens on the facebook developer site for the 'like box'.

[Facebook developer LikeBox page](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/)

Go there and switch off 'show faces and 'show header' and look at the bottom of the vertical scroll bar. It does not extend correctly to the bottom of the box?

Answer (score 0):

On the DOM item just below the likebox plugin, use **margin-top:-15px;** That should scoot it up  :)

Comment: Hi DMCS, Thank you for your prompt reply, but I have been unable to make this work. Just in case I am being really thick this morning - could you show an example (preferably an iframe one). Thanks again.

Comment: <div id="something-above"></div><div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/platform" data-width="292" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="true" data-header="false"></div><div id="something-below" style="margin-top:-15px;"></div>